# Calculate the price of the items, depending on its quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make block with the prices. The unit price varies depending on its quantity of units. For example:

```
Quantity — Price for each
1____________________$110
10___________________$105
20___________________$100
...
Number of items:__
Total:
Price for each:
```

There is a need to write a the text field into which the user enters the number of items, and everything is recalculating and summing on the fly.

Here is my realization of this task:

```js
var price1 = 110,
  price2 = 105,
  price3 = 100,
  qty1 = 1,
  qty2 = 10,
  qty3 = 20;

function conversion(val) {
  var div = document.getElementById("div"),
    price = document.getElementById("price");
  if (isNaN(val)) {
    div.innerHTML = "";
    price.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    switch (true) {
      case (val <= 0):
        {
          div.innerHTML = "";
          price.innerHTML = "";
          break;
        }
      case (val >= qty1 && val < qty2):
        {
          div.innerHTML = val * price1;
          price.innerHTML = price1;
          break;
        }
      case (val >= qty2 && val < qty3):
        {
          div.innerHTML = val * price2;
          price.innerHTML = price2;
          break;
        }
      case (val >= qty3):
        {
          div.innerHTML = val * price3;
          price.innerHTML = price3;
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Quantity — Price for each
</div>
<div>
  <div>1 — $110</div>
  <div>10 — $105</div>
  <div>20 — $100</div>
</div>
<div>
  Number of items:
  <div>
    <input id="txt" onblur="conversion(this.value)" onchange="conversion(this.value)" onkeypress="conversion(this.value)" onkeyup="conversion(this.value)" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Total:
  <div id="div"></div>
</div>
<div>
  Price for each:
  <div id="price"></div>
</div>
```

How it can be properly implemented, taking into account the fact that the lines with the quantity and unit price can be from one to infinity (values are taken from the database)?

I think it is possible to record the price and quantity in data-atributes and parse it with JS. Like this:

```
...
<div data-quantity="10" data-price="105">
  <span class="quantity">10</span>
  <span class="price">105</span>
</div>
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data attribute is indeed a solution:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("test").dataset)
```

```html
<div data-quantity="10" data-price="105" id="test">
  <span class="quantity">10</span>
  <span class="price">105</span>
</div>
```

It's [not fully compatible with previous IE version](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) though, so be careful with it.

I would however suggest that you look for a way of moving your calculations away from the DOM to speed up your calculations.

For instance, parsing the data to a JavaScript object and doing the calculations there would save you some DOM trips and thus speed:

```js
console.clear();
//markup for product
function Product(name) {
 return {
        //Name of product
  name : name,
        //List of price ranges (populated later)
  prices : [
  ],
        //method for adding a price
  newPrice : function newPrice(quantity, cost) {
            //Push new price unto list
   this.prices.push({
    quantity : quantity,
    cost : cost
   });
            //Sort list
   this.prices = this.prices.sort(function (a, b) {
     return a.quantity - b.quantity
    });
  },
        //Get the price for a variable quantity of this product
  get : function (quantity) {
   //Loop through prices to find the most matching
   var price = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < this.prices.length; i++) {
    if (this.prices[i].quantity <= quantity) {
     price = this.prices[i].cost;
    } else {
     break;
    }
   }
   console.log('price per unit:', price, 'price for all', quantity, 'units:', price * quantity)
  }
 };
} //Make an instance
var myHotProduct = new Product('Fancy pants');
//Add some prices
myHotProduct.newPrice(0, 110);
myHotProduct.newPrice(10, 105);
myHotProduct.newPrice(20, 100);
//get some quantities
myHotProduct.get(0);
myHotProduct.get(1);
myHotProduct.get(9);
myHotProduct.get(10);
myHotProduct.get(19);
myHotProduct.get(20);
//Log everything we know about our product
console.log(myHotProduct);
```

Now you can get your prices as arrays and modify them outside of the limitations of `data-`.